# How to prevent releases/deployments in repository with unrealisable changes?

Tags: deployment, gitlab-ci

We have two teams working on the same repository. However, each team is not aware of the other's work, and each pushes directly into the main branch of the repository. Releases to production are also made from this main branch.

A problem arises when one team needs to release code to production from the main branch, but there are unreleased commits from the other team. In such situations, the team must ask the other whether these commits can be deployed.

This approach isn't really convenient, as it requires regular communication with the other team every time a release is made, and we make releases quite often. Typically, their answer is "yes, you can release it."

I am wondering if there is a known solution to this problem. Ideally, the team with changes that haven't been released yet should be able to somehow prevent these releases from happening. For instance, GitLab CI/CD pipelines might skip the release step. I am aware of GitLab's Deploy Freeze, but it seems like it was designed with a different purpose in mind.